# MS Access Create Sales system with Product search

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm working on a form "frmSalesCreate". The idea is to create a new sales Invoice and print it at the end.

I have 2 subforms "sfrmSalesProdSearch" and "sfrmSalesProdList".

I am filtering the recordsource of the "sfrmSalesProdSearch" by a textbox.

```
    Private Sub btnSearchProd_Click()
Dim SQL As String

SQL = " SELECT Products.ProdID, Makes.MakeName, Products.ProdModel, ProdType.TypeName, Products.ProdDesc, Products.ProdPrice " _
    & " FROM ProdType INNER JOIN (Makes INNER JOIN Products ON Makes.MakeID = Products.ProdMake) ON ProdType.TypeID = Products.ProdTypeID " _
    & " WHERE (((Products.ProdModel) Like '*" & Me.txtSearchProd & "*')) " _
    & " OR (((Products.ProdBarcode) Like '*" & Me.txtSearchProd & "*')); "

Me.frmSalesProdSearch.Form.RecordSource = SQL
End Sub
```

The difficulty I am facing is how to take a selected result of the "sfrmSalesProdSearch" and insert it in to "sfrmSalesProdList".

Recordsource for "sfrmSalesProdList" is a temp table with relevant fields, which I intend to empty out before closing the main form. So that "sfrmSalesProdList" only shows data that is added when making a new sale.

I do not know if I have done a good job at explaining. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: By the way, is this the best way to achieve what I am trying to do? I am a novice at VBA. So any additional suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your invoice **ALWAYS** (emphasis on always) tie in with one and exactly one product model? Normal approach is to have an Invoice table and an Invoice Line table. Invoices are maintained through a form, Invoice Lines are maintained through a subform linked to the invoice form. You select product using a bound combo list in the subform.

Comment: Yes, normal approach is to save selected products to a table that is related to the Sales table. This is a 'paper trail' so sale's details would be documented and can be retrieved at any time in future. Allows more detailed analysis of activity. Are you saving only the gross sales amount to Sales table?

Comment: Yes I have invoice table, invoiceprod table and a teminvprod table. Idea was I would search the product from products table. Enter the selected product into tempinvprod table. Then the use append query or sql to enter all the products into invoiceprod table with invoice ID. So that I can call on the data in the future for reports. After saving the invoice delete all records in tempinvprod table. So that it is ready for the next new invoice.

Comment: Rene. No my invoice will have multiple products with variable quantity.

Comment: Why do you need intermediate temp table?

Comment: June7, I am using the temp table to show the list of products in the main form as it is added from the search result

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you are using this unconventional approach. I don't see need for temp table. Why not do data entry directly to target table?

Comment: Because I wanted to have the table empty at the beginning, add multiple products on the temp table and have it show on the form like list. And give the user ability to add quantity, change price sold at, add discount. And all of this is done on 3 different terminals so if I use the main table there will be a problem with priority of access to the table. So I thought if I use a local temp table, which is not going to be in the back end and I add the products as I like, then enter the edited data to the main table once the user clicks the button to save the sale. That was my chain of thought.

Comment: Does this make any sense? Or is there any other better way to tackle this scenario?